# Custom logger formatter in HTTParty

Tags: ruby, logging, command-line-interface, httparty

I would like to include automatic logging to my HTTParty requests, as part of a CLI app built with Thor.

I'm aware of `debug_output $stdout`, but the default formatters (`:apache` and `:curl`) do so much more than I want. I'd like to have extremely minimal logging that just outputs the request endpoint, params, and the response, along the lines of

```
PUT /users/123

{
  email: example@email.com
}

RESPONSE 201

{
  user: {
    id: 123,
    email: example@email.com
  }
}
```

I can see from HTTParty's specs that the Logger has an `add_formatter` method, which makes me wonder whether I can build a custom formatter, eg `SimpleFormatter`, and attach it to my class with something like

```
class API
  include HTTParty
  logger ::Logger.new("my simple logger"), :debug, :SimpleFormatter
end
```

But the example formatters in the source don't seem to subclass anything, so I'm unsure what interface my custom formatter should comply with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool idea.

You need to implement `initialize(logger, level)` and `format(request, response)` as per the sample curl and apache samples. Then you can add it to the formatters.

There's some properties you can use as well, but they don't seem to be mandatory.

```
attr_accessor :level, :logger, :current_time
```

I had a little play with the httparty example to see if it works, seems to work fine. Here's my sample and output.

**party.rb**

```
require 'httparty'
require 'logger'
require './custom_formatter.rb'

HTTParty::Logger.add_formatter('custom', HTTParty::Logger::CustomFormatter)

# Or wrap things up in your own class
class StackExchange
  include HTTParty
  logger ::Logger.new("a logger"), :debug, :custom
  base_uri 'api.stackexchange.com'

  def initialize(service, page)
    @options = { query: {site: service, page: page} }
  end

  def questions
    self.class.get("/2.2/questions", @options)
  end

  def users
    self.class.get("/2.2/users", @options)
  end
end

stack_exchange = StackExchange.new("stackoverflow", 1)
puts stack_exchange.questions
puts stack_exchange.users
```

**custom_formatter.rb**

```
module HTTParty
  module Logger
    class CustomFormatter 

      attr_accessor :level

      def initialize(logger, level)
        @logger = logger
        @level  = level.to_sym
      end

      def format(request, response)
        @logger.send @level, "hahahahaha "
      end
    end
  end
end
```

output:

```
--> D, [2016-06-02T22:30:26.613721 #5844] DEBUG -- : hahahahaha 
--> D, [2016-06-02T22:30:27.440348 #5844] DEBUG -- : hahahahaha
```